# Managing 3rd-party software with Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, build.gradle

You can use `mavenCentral()` to download jars and have them added to your classpath automatically. But what if you need to download a tarball and compile a `C` library to add to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in addition to the jar that is needed to compile and run?

Using Gradle, what do you think would be the best approach to incorporate this type of 3rd-party software into your build?

I don't think we can accomplish this declaratively, so my naive approach would be to create a task that downloads and extracts the tarball, compiles the software, and copies the libraries to build/lib or something, and make javaCompile depend upon it. Is there a better way? Would it be wise to put the task and libraries in buildSrc instead?

Our goals are to avoid redistributing software and to make it easier to use our software.

Our first example is [HDF Group's HDF5 tarball](https://www.hdfgroup.org/downloads/hdf5/source-code/). If you use this software, what was your approach?

Comment: You want to do this at build time? Or do you want your users to do this at runtime? What do you mean by “avoid redistributing software”?

Comment: I'm thinking build time so the user's don't have to worry about it. I was thinking buildSrc to avoid this process each time "gradle clean" is run.

For legal reasons, we can't include the 3rd-party source code or compiled libraries in our project's Git repository.

Comment: "*Our goals are to avoid redistributing software and to make it easier to use our software.*" - I do not really think that it is "*easier to use*" if you expect your users to have a C toolchain in addition to a Java toolchain. Also keep in mind that the C program might have further dependencies (e.g. some certain libs) that would have to be installed on the machine executing the build. I think it would be easier to provide pre-compiled `.so` or `.dll`-files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with. While it accomplishes my needs, I'm open to improving it. In `buildSrc/build.gradle`, I have:

```
apply from: "script-plugins/hdf5.gradle"
```

Here is `hdf5.gradle`:

```
// Download and build HDF5.
//
// TODO Next time around, parameterize the version and possibly the URL

task buildHdf5() {
    def tmp = file("$buildDir/tmp/hdf5")
    def hdf5 = file("$tmp/hdf5-1.12.2")
    def lib = file("$buildDir/lib")

    outputs.file "$lib/jarhdf5-1.12.2.jar"

    doLast() {
        tmp.mkdirs()

        // Use the SHA256 links at https://www.hdfgroup.org/downloads/hdf5/source-code/ to determine the URL.
        exec {
            workingDir tmp
            commandLine "curl", "-o", "hdf5-1.12.2.#1", "https://hdf-wordpress-1.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/manual/HDF5/HDF5_1_12_2/source/hdf5-1.12.2.{tar.bz2,sha256}"
        }
        exec {
            workingDir tmp
            commandLine "tar", "-xf", "hdf5-1.12.2.tar.bz2"
        }
        exec {
            workingDir hdf5
            commandLine "sh", "-c", "./configure --with-zlib=/usr --prefix=$buildDir --enable-threadsafe --with-pthread=/usr --enable-unsupported --enable-java"
        }
        exec {
            workingDir hdf5
            commandLine "make"
        }
        exec {
            workingDir hdf5
            commandLine "make", "install"
        }
        copy {
            from("$tmp/lib") {
                include "*.jar"
            }
            into "$lib"
        }
    }
}

assemble.dependsOn buildHdf5
```

In `gradle.properties`, I have:

```
ziggyDependencies = buildSrc/build
```

In `build.gradle`, I have:

```
ext.ziggyDependencies = "$rootDir/$ziggyDependencies"
…
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir {
        dirs "$ziggyDependencies/lib"
    }
}
…
dependencies {
    …
    compile ':jarhdf5:1.12.+'
    …
```

And that's it!